# Overall constant for the scalar propagator in AdS background

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

I am trying to solve Exercise 3.3 in [*TASI Lectures on AdS/CFT*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04948) by João Penedones. It is solving for the scalar propagator $\Pi(X,Y)$ in AdS, and states as follows:

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \frac{1}{2} J_{AB}J^{BA} \phi &= [X^2 \partial_X^2 + X \cdot \partial_X (d + X \cdot \partial_X)]\phi,
> \tag{62}\label{62}
> \\
> \frac{1}{2} J_{AB}J^{BA} \phi &= R^2 \nabla_{AdS}^2 \phi,
> \tag{64}\label{64}
> \\
> \left[\nabla_X^2 - m^2\right] \Pi(X,Y) &= - \delta^{d+1}(X,Y).
> \tag{72}\label{72}
> \end{align}
> $$
> Use \eqref{62} and \eqref{64} to show that
> $$
> \Pi(X,Y) = \frac{\mathcal{C}_\Delta}{\zeta^\Delta} \sideset{_2}{_1}{F} \left(\Delta, \Delta-\frac{d}{2}+\frac{1}{2},2\Delta-d+1, -\frac{4}{\zeta}\right),
> \tag{73}\label{73}
> $$
> where $\zeta=\frac{(X-Y)^2}{R^2}=(X-Y)^2$ ($R$ is set to 1), $2\Delta=d+\sqrt{d^2+(2m)^2}$, and
> $$
> \mathcal{C}_\Delta = \frac{\Gamma(\Delta)}{2 \pi^{\frac{d}{2}} \Gamma(\Delta-\frac{d}{2}+1)}.
> \tag{74}\label{74}
> $$

I am able to obtain a differential equation for $\Pi(X,Y)$ as a function of $\zeta$,
$$
(\zeta^2 + 4\zeta) \frac{\partial^2 \Pi}{\partial \zeta^2} + (d+1)(\zeta + 2) \frac{\partial \Pi}{\partial \zeta} - \Delta(\Delta-d) \Pi = - \delta(\zeta),
$$
which I think is solved by \eqref{73} up to an overall constant. To fix the constant $\mathcal{C}_\Delta$, the instructor suggested to integrate \eqref{72} over a region $R(Y)$ around the point $Y$,
<sup>1</sup>
$$
\int_{R(Y)} dX \left[\nabla_X^2 - m^2\right] \Pi(X,Y) = -1,
$$
and perform integration by parts to measure the flux.
However, I don't know how to parametrise the surface of $R(Y)$ and perform the surface integral to measure the flux. I would really appreciate it if someone can give me some guidance on how to proceed with this integral. Thanks!

<sup><sup>1</sup> From my understanding, the region $R(Y)$ is arbitrary, and is supposed to shrink to zero at the end.</sup>